# How to check if a DFP Ad unit has content

Tags: google-dfp

I have an ad zone from DFP and I want to find a way to check if the ad unit has content (ad)

I m reading this https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference but I have difficulties

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

My experience is that this is not reliably possible.

You can implement an event handler that is notified if ad is loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/images/js/dfp.js"></script> 

<script type='text/javascript'>
  skyscaperHasContent = false;

  function renderEnded() {
    skyscaperHasContent = true;
  }

  googletag.cmd.push(function() { 
    googletag.defineSlot('/123456/leaderboard', [[728, 90]], 'div-gpt-ad-1234567890').addService(googletag.pubads()); 
    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest(); 
    googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', renderEnded); 
    googletag.enableServices(); 
  }); 
</script>
```

However, if you have a complex DfP setup and forward certain ad requests to networks, then DfP might simply insert the tag from a network and call the *renderEnded* event. It will even insert an IFRAME of the expected size around the network tag.

In such a case, the event is always triggered and it's even triggered before the network has answered. But the network might be unable to fill the slot and the ad unit remains empty. So it's might not be usable in your case.